# How to avoid / troubleshoot on-page refreshing bug in Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, bugs, webview

I've been experiencing a bug since the upgrade to Lollipop, perhaps even earlier, where the current tab refreshes *while I'm looking at it*. This has been very difficult to find info about, because of the hordes of people complaining about the ordinary, reasonable behaviour of Android refreshing hidden tabs when they're reopened.

It seems like it might have something to do with memory or excessive JS usage as it appears to happen more on slow, content heavy sites. Lightweight sites with simple HTML are barely affected. It also has nothing to do with any particular interaction, as I've seen it happen while reading articles having not touched the screen for a few minutes.

I've tried reinstalling Chrome and restarting my device, but I suspect this could be a problem with the underlying webview or device as I've seen a similar thing happening in other apps as well.

Does anyone know if this is a common problem? Anyone run into this and find a fix?

Nexus 5

Android 6.0.1

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: @LJD200 Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1

Comment: Does this happen with other browsers such as Opera or Firefox?

Comment: @LJD200 I think the answer is no, but it's difficult to confirm that. So far I have not seen it happen on mobile FF, but I have seen it recently on Chrome.

Comment: Try force stopping Chrome and then wiping the cache and data for the app. Note that all bookmarks, cookies, passwords, etc. stored in Chrome will be erased.

Comment: @LJD200 I have tried doing that in addition to reinstalling Chrome, with no luck. I'll try your suggestion again without signing in with my Google account - perhaps it's a tab/bookmark syncing bug that's tied to my account.

Comment: This is an odd error. Please do try this but I'm not sure it will help.